# Can't delete paragraph break in ms-word

Tags: microsoft-word

I cannot delete this break in the file, here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PC2_g-JRW8ewY7Zh7pcojjsuiqb6ZCso/view?usp=sharing

Its the last thing in the file. I want to start typing on the line after the date but it goes to the next page. The doc is not tracking changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You file shows that there is break that creates the new page. Put the cursor on the right of 2020, Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice. Then, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Down</kbd> to select the break and what's found on the next page. Then, press Delete. You should be able to write after 2020

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works as far as it goes. I didn't state the full extent of the issue. Now the 'sfsgjggj...' is in the 2nd column. I want the document to switch to 1 column after the date. How do I do that?

Comment: @AlLelopath Select that 'sfsgjggj...', Go to Layout tab, Columns -> One.